# Use Variable as TempParam in function

Tags: javascript, php, function, email, variables

I'm fairly new to coding, but i'm using my website to manage inscriptions for my small sportsbusiness.

I want my site to send an email to the user after sending data to my database.
So the user fills in a form and on 'submit' is transferred to an php-page that sends the data to the database.
Onload this page triggers a function that sends the email using EmailJS.

This all works, but i'm struggling with the tempParams that I need to personalize this mail.
while testing the mailing service I used 'document.getElementById' to get the parameters but this doesn't work since the element was on the previous page. I have the elements I need further down in my php as variables to be send to the database. so I should be able to write these into the function as parameters for EmailJS

this is what the function looks like:

```
 <head>
    <script>
        function sendMail(param) {
            var tempParams ={
                mail_to: document.getElementById("email").value,
                name_event: document.getElementById("eventname").value,
                name_part: document.getElementById("participant").value,
                price: document.getElementById("price").value,
            };
        emailjs.send('service_#######','template_#######',tempParams)
        .then(function(res){
            console.log("success", res.status);
            })
        }
    </script>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@3/dist/email.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
        emailjs.init("user_9R#######");
        })();
    </script>
    
  </head>
  <body onLoad="sendMail()">

    $name_event = $_POST['eventname'];
    $name_part = $_POST['participant'];
    $mail_to = $_POST['email'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
```

So to put my question:
How do I put PHP-variables as TempParams in my javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to include your PHP variables directly in the javascript.

```php
        function sendMail(param) {
            var tempParams ={
                mail_to: "<?php $_POST['email'] ?>",
                name_event: "<?php $_POST['eventname'] ?>",
                name_part: "<?php $_POST['participant'] ?>",
                price: <?php $_POST['price'] ?>,
            };
```

Don't forget to escape quotes in user data so it doesn't break the JS.

Comment: doing so gives no output in the email
the TempParams for EmailJS ( {{mail_to}}, {{name_event}}, {{name_part}}, {{price}} ) stay empty

Comment: Did you try to right click / inspect source code to see the result?